# Bash, Remove empty XML tags

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed

I need some help a couple of questions, using bash tools

1. I want to remove empty xml tags from a file eg:

```xml
 <CreateOfficeCode>
      <OperatorId>ve</OperatorId>
      <OfficeCode>1234</OfficeCode>
      <CountryCodeLength>0</CountryCodeLength>
      <AreaCodeLength>3</AreaCodeLength>
      <Attributes></Attributes>
      <ChargeArea></ChargeArea>
 </CreateOfficeCode>
```

to become:

```xml
 <CreateOfficeCode>
      <OperatorId>ve</OperatorId>
      <OfficeCode>1234</OfficeCode>
      <CountryCodeLength>0</CountryCodeLength>
      <AreaCodeLength>3</AreaCodeLength>
 </CreateOfficeCode>
```

for this I have done so by this command

```
sed -i '/><\//d' file
```

which is not so strict, its more like a trick, something more appropriate would be to find the `<pattern></pattern>` and remove it. Suggestion?

2. Second, how to go from:

```xml
 <CreateOfficeGroup>
       <CreateOfficeName>John</CreateOfficeName>
       <CreateOfficeCode>
       </CreateOfficeCode>
 </CreateOfficeGroup>
```

to:

```xml
 <CreateOfficeGroup>
       <CreateOfficeName>John</CreateOfficeName>
 </CreateOfficeGroup>
```

3. As a whole thing? from:

```xml
 <CreateOfficeGroup>
       <CreateOfficeName>John</CreateOfficeName>
       <CreateOfficeCode>
            <OperatorId>ve</OperatorId>
            <OfficeCode>1234</OfficeCode>
            <CountryCodeLength>0</CountryCodeLength>
            <AreaCodeLength>3</AreaCodeLength>
            <Attributes></Attributes>
            <ChargeArea></ChargeArea>
       </CreateOfficeCode>
       <CreateOfficeSize>
            <Chairs></Chairs>
            <Tables></Tables>
       </CreateOfficeSize>
 </CreateOfficeGroup>
```

to:

```xml
 <CreateOfficeGroup>
       <CreateOfficeName>John</CreateOfficeName>
       <CreateOfficeCode>
            <OperatorId>ve</OperatorId>
            <OfficeCode>1234</OfficeCode>
            <CountryCodeLength>0</CountryCodeLength>
            <AreaCodeLength>3</AreaCodeLength>
       </CreateOfficeCode>
 </CreateOfficeGroup>
```

Can you answer the questions as individuals? Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't use bash/string processing for this. Use a tool made for processing XML. Something like XSLT or a real XML parser and a script in a language that lets you walk the resulting document and remove elements.

Comment: Is the syntax error with a backslash instead of a slash intetional?  This isn't valid XML, and most XML processing tools will choke on it.  (Granted, that may well be the reason you are looking for a `sed` solution...)

Comment: @tripleee sorry, it was a typo about the slashes

Comment: @Etan Reisner why should he use an XML processing tool, having to deal with all the miseries coming from using such a stuff while taking benefit of a negligible amount of its functionality? It's a simple text processing task which can easily be achieved with awk or sed.

Comment: I prefer to use sed or awk because these may be added later to an existing script

Comment: @GézaTörök Because it is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true story, there's no misery here :) but one more reason is that sed is widely available on unix systems, while such a tool must most likely be installed.

Comment: @GézaTörök, to be sure, but because `sed` doesn't know XML syntax, any attempt to modify XML with `sed` is doomed to be incorrect. It doesn't know what is or isn't in a CDATA section, it doesn't know what is or isn't in a comment... you simply cannot parse XML accurately with sed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i admit in a general case.

Comment: as GézaTörök mentions, sed is available on unix. In my case I cannot install any other tools in the server (not even with private binaries) so I have to make do with whatever is available.
In this case the xmls are small SOAP messages so its not so worrying

Comment: @thahgr: Do you have a modern Python interpreter? If so, that includes a proper XML parser.

Comment: Alternately, does your system have `xsltproc`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, a python interpreter is available too, and it would do the trick, so in that case I should use XMLStarlet?
Still, I would prefer sed or awk since there are existing ksh scripts to be modified
Yes again, xsltproc is available, first time I hear of it though :)

Comment: @thahgr, it's easy to embed or call Python from your shell scripts. `sed` and `awk` simply do not have the tools to edit XML reliably and accurately. (There are awk-inspired tools that do, but that again would mean installing something).

Comment: I need to run right now, but will put together an embedded-Python solution if nobody else has already done so yet when more time is available. Could you note the Python version(s) available on your server?

Comment: it is Python 2.6.9,
thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64254/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-thahgr).

Comment: is it possible with `xmllint` to remove empty tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '#n
1h;1!H
$ { x
:remtag
  s#\(\n* *\)*<\([^>]*>\)\( *\n*\)*</\2##g
  t remtag

  p
  }' YourFile
```

(posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed)

- recursively remove empty tag from lower lever to upper one until no more empty tag occur.
- Not a XML parser so something like `<tag1 prop="<tag2></tag2>"> ...` will remove the prop content also and any other thing like that that xml allow.

Comment: I'm rather strongly opposed to any use of non-syntax-aware tools for parsing/generation of structured content (just because someone doesn't _expect_ getting the corner cases wrong to matter doesn't mean those corner cases can't be leveraged in a security exploit or won't cause someone to lose a day of productivity tracking down a bug in an almost-unrelated component that calls something using this one years later)... but even I need to give this a +1.

Comment: I agree but sometimes other tools than 'basic one' are not allowed (this is my case) and some non XML parser, used with the knowledge of the limitation is the only solution in a short term. For a long term, think of the adapted tools (but unhoppefully, often solution are temporary long term ...)

Comment: I had a few thousand errors importing an xml file that worked on other tools, and no idea how many problems there were. This quickly did the job, removed the clutter. I could quickly find the remaining problems and verify the original import tool. For my use case, your sed was a perfect find. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sf.net/) is a command-line XML processor. Doing what you want with it is a one-line operation (until the desired recursive behavior is added), and will work for all variants of XML syntax describing the same input:

The simple version:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -d '//*[not(./*) and (not(./text()) or normalize-space(./text())="")]' \
  input.xml
```

The fancy version:

```
strip_recursively() {
  local doc last_doc
  IFS= read -r -d '' doc 
  while :; do
    last_doc=$doc
    doc=$(xmlstarlet ed \
           -d '//*[not(./*) and (not(./text()) or normalize-space(./text())="")]' \
           /dev/stdin <<<"$last_doc")
    if [[ $doc = "$last_doc" ]]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$doc"
      return
    fi
  done
}
strip_recursively <input.xml
```

`/dev/stdin` is used rather than `-` (at some cost to platform portability) for better portability across releases of XMLStarlet; adjust to taste.

---

With a system having only older dependencies installed, a more likely XML parser to have installed is that bundled with Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import sys

doc = etree.parse(sys.stdin)
def prune(parent):
    ever_changed = False
    while True:
        changed = False
        for el in parent.getchildren():
            if len(el.getchildren()) == 0:
                if ((el.text is None or el.text.strip() == '') and
                    (el.tail is None or el.tail.strip() == '')):
                    parent.remove(el)
                    changed = True
            else:
                changed = changed or prune(el)
        ever_changed = changed or ever_changed
        if changed is False:
            return ever_changed

prune(doc.getroot())
print etree.tostring(doc.getroot())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following with sed:

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/<\([^>]*\)>[ \t\n]*<\/\1>//g;s/\([\n][\t\n ]*[\n]\)/\n/g;' yourfile.xml
```

The script at the beginning (`:l;N;$!bl`) appends all the lines together to the pattern space by a loop (:a - declares label a; N - append next line to the pattern space; $!bl - branch to a if last line is not reached)

The pattern of the first substitution is built up like opening tag (`<\([^>]*\)>`) - optional whitespace (`[ \t\n]*`) - closing tag (`<\/\1>`). Note the escaped parens surrounding the pattern for tag name, whose contents can be referred to as \1 afterwards in the expression. This is how the closing tag matches the opening tag.

Finally, the second substitution (`s/[\n][\n]*/\n/g`) simply removes consecutive newlines.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in a test here at all. It also doesn't appear to handle elements with attributes (assuming it worked in the first place). There aren't any in the input but that may not hold true for the actual data. This also doesn't appear to handle `<tag>\n</tag>` (despite the inclusion of `\n` in that whitespace class because `sed` is line-oriented.

Comment: Leaves blank lines now. Now do you see my point about using an XML tool for this? =)

Comment: Ok, let's say i'm convinced :)